# linq left join - select property of left entity

Tags: linq

I keep getting an ArgumentNullException "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: inner" with the following linq:

```
var dataSource = (from v in vouchers
                  join payAdj in paymentAdjustments on v.VoId equals payAdj.VoId into pTemp
                  from p in pTemp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                  select new
                  {
                    VoId = v.VoId,
                    OpId = v.OpId,
                    PaValue = p.PaValue
                  });
```

Both vouchers and paymentAdjustments are lists of entities.

I've read a lot of posts around this and everything I try keeps giving me the same (or similar) error.

- casting PaValue to a nullable decimal i.e PaValue = (decimal?)p.PaValue
- testing p for null before accessing PaValue i.e. PaValue = p != null ? p.PaValue : (decimal)0
- using SingleOrDefault (there should only be one) instead of DefaultIfEmpty
- doing a nested select instead of the join...into i.e. PaValue = (from p in paymentAdjustments
                                                                 where p.VoId == v.VoId
                                                                 select p.PaValue).DefaultIfEmpty()

I'm using c# 2010 Express and .Net 4.

Any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks
Marlyn

Comment: Your query looks fine. Can you tell us more about `vouchers` and `paymentsAdjustments`? Are they just collections? If so, can you provide the type definitions?

Comment: Did you every solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but for anyone searching for an answer, one of the two objects you are joining on is null.  Do this first.

if (vouchers != null && payAdjustments != null)
     ...

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = from case in dbEntity.Cases
            join Comm in dbEntity.Comms on case.log_id equals comm.CaseId into collection
            from subCase in collection.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new { Case=case,Status= (subCase==null?null:subcase.Status };
```